# Angular ui bootstrap custom templates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I use the custom templates of angular ui bootstrap in rails?

I mean, if I use `pagination` for example it will look for a `templates/pagination/pagination.html` template.

The problem is that rails won't serve templates in that path, it actually needs to be `assets/templates/pagination/pagination.html` using the `<%= asset_path(....) %>` helper.

Hacking the angular ui bootstrap javascript file is a way, but I don't feel like hacking it every time I get a new version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would suggest is to bundle custom templates with the library itself or inside a separate file. The technique to use is to fill in `$templateCache` with the content of your custom templates. Have a look at one of the files distributed with tamplates to see what I mean:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js#L2042

You can bundle templates into the `$templateCache` as part of the build process or prepare this file manually (in this case you need to write templates as JS strings).

Downloading individual templates via XHR for each and every directive would be wasteful as it would result in many XHR requests and would slow down your application. Also, if you preload templates into the `$templateCache` you can specify required path, one that doesn't need to be a valid path on your WWW server.

Comment: That is awesome, $templateCache doesn't have documentation but I figured out. Is good to know that I can provide a `name` and if some directive looks for a template with that name, I can provide what I want. I will update my question with what I ended doing just for sake of sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

I use bower to manage my js libs.
Hence I have these files in my `vendor/assets/javascripts/` folder:
[angular-ui/bootstrap-bower](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower)

With these files, you can simply require them in your javascript manifest file (usually application.js)

```
//= require angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap
//= require angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls
```

and then you don't need to specify any templates if you want to use the default built-in templates.

I find this solution in the following url
Ref:[angular-ui-bootstrap-directive-template-missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961498/angular-ui-bootstrap-directive-template-missing)

Comment: Thanks, but the idea was using my own templates. Anyway, I ended with lineman to create angular apps and then dump it into a rails public folder.